# Way to run .NET application on Win7 without installing anything?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, portable

We have a few special computers that are for security reasons offline and use W7 with some tweaks. I cannot install anything on these machines, all I can do is run a portable program.

I would need to run my .NET application, is there any way I could run it without having to install .NET framework; something like pre-compiling it with linked all the libraries and then run it as a stand-alone app, like .NET native does for W10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the article
[What version of the .NET Framework is included in what version of the OS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/),
Windows 7 includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component.
This means you will have available the .NET Framework 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2
and 3.5 SP1 plus a few post 3.5 SP1 bug fixes.
You will not see it in Programs and Features because it is built-in.

So all you have to do is to downgrade your app to .NET 3 and it will run.

If you are using Visual Studio 2017, it might be possible to package the
.Net Framework with the application. See the Microsoft blog:
[Package a .NET desktop application using the Desktop Bridge and Visual Studio Preview](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2017/08/28/package-a-net-desktop-application-using-the-desktop-bridge-and-visual-studio-preview/).

Comment: The thing you say about packaging a .NET application with Desktop Bridge is only relevant for Win10, and refers to a way to distribute non-Windows-Store apps (either Win32 or .NET) through the Windows Store. It has nothing to do with packaging an entire .NET framework with your app; in fact, Desktop Bridge apps, if they use .NET at all, need to target a specific version of it (4.6.2, if memory serves). With that said, the stuff about just making your app target .NET 2.0-3.5.1 and distributing it as-is will work for Win7 (just don't package it in a Win10 .APPX bundle!)